# How To Access Magento Navigation Order Property

Tags: php, sorting, magento, navigation

I'm not great at Magento by any means, so I'm not looking for the perfect answer but some direction would be greatly appreciated.

In my Magento site.
Under Catalog -> Manage Categories.

You can drag and drop the categories and sub categories to reorganize them.

However this does not change the order on the frontend.

I had previously added a sorting logic to:

/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php

Which was added inside of the function renderCategoryMenuItemHtml

That works well to sort the categories alphabetically:

```
   $_tmp_children = array();
    foreach ($activeChildren as $child) {
        if ($child->getIsActive()) {
            $_tmp_children[$child->getName()] = $child;
        }
    }
    ksort($_tmp_children,SORT_STRING);
```

I had assumed that just reverting to the original would have sorted by the position in the admin area, but that is not the case.

Does anyone know how the property the I could access or method I could call instead of getName() that would get the property for 'position' ?

I've tried just doing $child->position and variations of that.

Comment: The problem was actually in the code I had added pair with the website's caching, once I removed the code and clear the cache the problem solved itself.

Another problem was that there were a number of overwrites tot he navigation, because it had a custom template, so I had to find the correct file to edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I removed the code I mentioned (In the correct file) the problem solved itself, the Navigation sorts by position automatically.